# how to insert new data in customised Qtableview?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside2

I have a `QTableView` implemented by `QAbstractTableModel` and `QStyledItemDelegate`. For the model data, it has 4 dimensions, 'name', 'age', 'sex', 'phone number'. But in the tableview I want to display them in 3 columns, name and age in one column, the other two placed in their own columns.

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication,QTableView, QStyledItemDelegate,QStyleOptionViewItem,QStyle, QPushButton,QWidget,QVBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QTextDocument, QPainter,QFont,QAbstractTextDocumentLayout, QPalette,QTextCursor,QTextCharFormat, QTextBlockFormat,QFontMetrics


class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, mydata):
        super().__init__()
        self._tabledata = mydata

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return len(self._tabledata)

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return len(self._tabledata[0] if self._tabledata else [])

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if index.row() >= self.rowCount():
            return None
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            return self._tabledata[index.row()][index.column()]

        else:
            return None

    def insertNewRow(self):

        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0)
        self._tabledata.append(['test','20','female', 234])
        self.endInsertRows()

class TableDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.column() in [0, 3, 2]:
            painter.save()
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            widget = option.widget
            style = widget.style()         
            style.drawControl(style.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter, widget)   
            painter.restore()

        if index.column() == 0:
            
            self.doc = QTextDocument(self)
            colWid = option.rect.width()
            painter.save()
            painter.setPen(QColor(244,243,243,255))
            painter.drawLine(option.rect.bottomLeft(), option.rect.bottomRight())
            
            options = QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
            self.initStyleOption(options, index)
            self.doc.setPlainText('')
  
            cursor = QTextCursor(self.doc)
            fmt = QTextCharFormat()
            fmt.setFontFamily('Aria')
            fmt.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
            fmt.setFontPointSize(10)
            serifFont = QFont("Aria", 10, QFont.Bold)
            fm = QFontMetrics(serifFont)
            cursor.setCharFormat(fmt)
            cursor.beginEditBlock()
            cursor.insertText(fm.elidedText(options.text, Qt.ElideRight, colWid -10))
            fmt.setBackground(Qt.red)
        
            cursor.endEditBlock()
            tbm = QTextBlockFormat()
            tbm.setTopMargin(10)
            cursor.insertBlock(tbm)
            cursor.beginEditBlock()
            fmt.setBackground(Qt.transparent)
            fmt.setFontWeight(QFont.Normal)
            fmt.setFontPointSize(8)

            fmt.setForeground(QColor(123,123,123,255))
            cursor.setCharFormat(fmt)
            serifFont = QFont("Aria", 8, QFont.Normal)
            fm = QFontMetrics(serifFont)
            elidedstr = fm.elidedText(index.model().data(index.siblingAtColumn(1), Qt.DisplayRole), Qt.ElideRight, colWid -10)
            cursor.insertText(elidedstr)
            fmt.setBackground(Qt.red)
            cursor.endEditBlock()

            ctx = QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
            if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
                ctx.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                    QPalette.Active, QPalette.HighlightedText))
            else:
                ctx.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                    QPalette.Active, QPalette.Text))

            textRect = option.widget.style().subElementRect(QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)
     
            textRect.adjust(5, 0, 0, 0)
            textRect.setTop(textRect.top())
            painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
            self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

            painter.restore()
        
        else:
            QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)


class MyTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(40)
        self.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.setFixedWidth(300)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = QWidget()
    lyt = QVBoxLayout()
    myWindow.setLayout(lyt)

    t = MyTableView()
    t.setItemDelegate(TableDelegate())
    m = MyTableModel([['mike', '12', 'male', 124], ['jack', '15', 'male', 123]])
    t.setModel(m)
    t.setColumnHidden(1, True)

    btn = QPushButton('new')
    btn.clicked.connect(m.insertNewRow)
    lyt.addWidget(btn)
    lyt.addWidget(t)

    myWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and in the `QTableview`, I will hide column 1.

in the `QStyledItemDelegate`, I will inplemented the `paint` method to make the column 0 to show both name and age somehow.

it works in this way so far.

----------update, the code works for adding new data--------------

But when I want to insert a new data record into the table(the code I didn't place here), the hidden column will show up again, which means I 've to hide them again.

new to Model/Delegate programming in PySide2.

Hope to get some advice.

Comment: We cannot provide an answer related to code that you are not showing. Please provide a valid [mre] (and ensure that the post preview also shows correct syntax, as right now your code has indentation issues), including the part in which you add new data. Also: 1. you have 4 *columns*, not *dimensions*; 2. a model should not have its data stored as a class attribute, but as an *instance* attribute; 3. what's the point of creating local variables for the index row and column if you don't use it? 4. similarly, what's the point of overriding `__init__` if you're not doing anything else there?

Comment: @musicamante thanks, the code works if the model data is not None before set model to the Qtableview, otherwise, I need to hide the column then.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. You say that when adding a new row the hidden column appears again, but according to your code it doesn't. Please try to make yourself more clear. Note that your implementation of the delegate has some serious issues (besides being much more complex than it should), most importantly the fact that you create a *new* QTextDocument with the delegate as a parent (which is pointless) at each call of `paint`. That creates a **serious** memory leak, as you'll easily end up with hundreds if not thousands of QTextDocument objects that are not used anymore but still exist.

Comment: @musicamante I create QTextDocument for display text in two lines and set highlight for some characters if necessary. Sorry for the previous problem I mentioned which is really not that clear. After second check, if set ```m = MyTableModel([])``` at first, that is to say, no model data for the tableview initialization, and then click the "new" button, there will be no rows inserted into the tableview

Comment: I know why you use QTextDocument, that's not what I was referring to (please read my comment more carefully): the issue is not about using QTextDocument, but how you **create** it: the `self` argument (which indicates the parent that will eventually take its ownership) is wrong and pointless, especially since you're creating an instance attribute that will be overwritten at the next `paint()` call (and that function is called **very** often). At the very least, you should create it just *once* (possibly, in the `__init__` of the delegate) and then update its contents and properties.

Comment: Then, the problem is quite obvious: when you initialize the model with an empty list, `columnCount()` returns 0, and, theoretically, it's correct: there's no data, so there's no column. The problem is that when you try to add a row, you are not notifying that **also** the column count has changed: adding a row doesn't change the columns. Either you always specify an hardcoded column count (in your case, 4), or you also call the related `beginInsertColumns()` and `endInsertColumns()`. Remember that a table model can have a column count even if it doesn't have any row (and vice-versa).

Comment: If you can confirm that your initial statement (the hidden column of the horizontal header being "reset" at row insertion) was wrong, and that your actual issue is about not having visible data after creating an empty model and adding rows, I'll eventually add an answer.